# remove all items from array that has {error} in it

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to filter out `{objects}` from array that has `{error}` in it.
based on query there would be more items like this, so I need a solution that filters out all `{error}` objects from array

[image]

Comment: `let newArray = array.filter(item => !item.error)`

Comment: Or, `let newArray = array.filter(item => !item.hasOwnProperty("error"))` if the value of the `.error` property can be anything including a falsey value such as `0` or an empty string or `false`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks Mate, you first option worked.

Comment: This question as written doesn't have anything to do with Node or React -- all it has is a request for a solution with a screenshot of a browser console. Questions on StackOverflow need to have a [mcve] showing your attempted solution along with a problem description. Take a look at the [help] and [ask]. Also, a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=JavaScript+filter+objects+from+array) would have given you a great amount of helpful information.

Comment: @Herohtar Thanks mate, will keep in mind next time. Just a beginner type mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter on the error property:

```
let newArray = array.filter(item => !item.error);
```

Or, if the value of the `.error` property can be anything including a falsey value such as `0` or an empty string or `false`:

```
let newArray = array.filter(item => !item.hasOwnProperty("error"))
```